# Convert Hash Into And Array Of Strings

Tags: ruby

```
{"offer:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "offer:index"=>["0"], "offer:new"=>["0"], "offer:show"=>["0"], "offer:create"=>["0"], "offer:update"=>["0"], "offer:destroy"=>["0"], "job:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "job:index"=>["0", "1"], "job:new"=>["0"], "job:create"=>["0"], "job:edit"=>["0"], "job:update"=>["0"], "job:destroy"=>["0"], "user:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "user:index"=>["0"], "user:new"=>["0"], "user:create"=>["0"], "user:edit"=>["0"], "user:update"=>["0"], "user:destroy"=>["0"], "account_access:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "role:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "role:index"=>["0"], "role:new"=>["0"], "role:create"=>["0"], "role:edit"=>["0"], "role:update"=>["0"], "role:destroy"=>["0"], "welcome_package:manage_all"=>["0", "1"]}
```

I need to convert this hash into a string.

If the key has a value of 1 the key needs to be pushed to a an array.

The above will has will need to equal this because they are the keys with a value that includes 1.

```
["offer:manage_all", "job:manage_all", "job:index", "account_access:manage_all", "role:manage_all", "welcome_package:manage_all"]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In future, it's easier for the reader if you give an example that is as small as possible but still [covers all the bases](http://grammarist.com/usage/cover-all-the-bases/). Also, it's helpful if you assign a variable to each of the example's input objects (e.g., `h = { "offer:manage_all"...}`) so that readers can refer to the variable (`h`) in answers and comments without having to define it (and all readers reference the same variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try method `select` and `keys`

```
hash = {"offer:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "offer:index"=>["0"], "offer:new"=>["0"], "offer:show"=>["0"], "offer:create"=>["0"], "offer:update"=>["0"], "offer:destroy"=>["0"], "job:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "job:index"=>["0", "1"], "job:new"=>["0"], "job:create"=>["0"], "job:edit"=>["0"], "job:update"=>["0"], "job:destroy"=>["0"], "user:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "user:index"=>["0"], "user:new"=>["0"], "user:create"=>["0"], "user:edit"=>["0"], "user:update"=>["0"], "user:destroy"=>["0"], "account_access:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "role:manage_all"=>["0", "1"], "role:index"=>["0"], "role:new"=>["0"], "role:create"=>["0"], "role:edit"=>["0"], "role:update"=>["0"], "role:destroy"=>["0"], "welcome_package:manage_all"=>["0", "1"]}

keys = hash.select{ |key,val| val.include? "1" }.keys

#=> ["offer:manage_all", "job:manage_all", "job:index", "user:manage_all", "account_access:manage_all", "role:manage_all", "welcome_package:manage_all"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the hash:

```
h = {"cat"=>["0", "1"], "dog"=>["0"], "pig"=>["0", "1"], "owl"=>["0"], "hen"=>["0", "1"] }
```

I would write

```
h.keys.select { |k| h[k].include? "1" }
  #=> ["cat", "pig", "hen"]
```